# Add .PNG to relative folder path in R

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using knitr to create a markdown file with multiple images in them. As I don't want to typ the path each time, I want it to be relative.

`mainDir <- ~/Documents/R/Images/
subDir <- Logo
color <- blue`

Now I would like to add '.png' to print the actual image. And I don't want to change color to `<- blue.png` as I'm using the variable 'blue' in other parts of the code.

`img1 <-  rasterGrob(as.raster(readPNG(file.path(mainDir, subDir, color, ".png"))), interpolate = FALSE)`

I get the following error:
Error in readPNG(file.path(mainDir, subDir, img, ".png")) : 
  unable to open /Documents/R/Images/Logo/blue/.png

How can I delete the last "/", so that it would be 'blue.png' instead of blue/.png?

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
mainDir <- "~/Documents/R/Images" 
subDir <- "Logo"
color <- "blue`
file.path(mainDir, subDir, paste(color, ".png",sep=""))
```

Result:
"~/Documents/R/Images/Logo/blue.png"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `paste` function which will concatenate the file extension on to the path string.

`img1 <-  rasterGrob(as.raster(readPNG(paste(file.path(mainDir, subDir, color), ".png", sep = ""))), interpolate = FALSE)`

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/RHOME/library/base/html/paste.html

Also, you don't need the trailing `/` on the `mainDir <- "~/Documents/R/Images"`, as it will be duplicated when you add the subdir.